# Robin carp implementation does not give the desired result

Tags: c++, rabin-karp

The below code is not giving the desired output after using 1000000007 to hash.

Using 101 to hash make it work desirably.
Can you help me in finding the where I am getting wrong?

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef vector< int > vi;
typedef vector< vi > vvi;
typedef pair< int,int > ii;
#define rep(i,a,b) for(int i=a;i<b;i++)
#define sz(a) int((a).size())
#define pb push_back
#define all(c) (c).begin(),(c).end()
#define tr(c,i) for(typeof((c)).begin() i = (c).begin(); i != (c).end(); i++)
#define present(c,x) ((c).find(x) != (c).end())
#define cpresent(c,x) (find(all(c),x) != (c).end())

int val(char s)
{
        return int(s)-int('A')+1;
}
void robinkarp(string text,string compare,int q)
{
    int hashofcompare=0;
    int windowhash=0;
    int valchanger=1;
    for(int i=0;i<compare.size();i++)
    {
        hashofcompare=(hashofcompare*26+val(compare[i]))%q;
        windowhash=(windowhash*26+val(text[i]))%q;
        if(i!=0)
            valchanger=(valchanger*26)%q;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<=text.size()-compare.size();i++)
    {
        if(windowhash==hashofcompare)
        {
            int j=0;
            for(;j<compare.size();j++)
            {
                if(val(compare[j])!=val(text[i+j]))
                    break;
            }
            if(j==compare.size())
                cout<<"Found at:"<<i+1<<"\n";
        }
        if(i!=text.size()-compare.size())
            windowhash=(26*((windowhash-valchanger*(val(text[i])))%q)+val(text[i+compare.size()]))%q;
        windowhash=(windowhash+q)%q;
    }
}
int main()
{
    string text;
    cin>>text;
    string compare;
    cin>>compare;
    int prime=1000000009;
    cout<<prime;
    robinkarp(text,compare,prime);

}
```

Showing no ouput for the input case:deeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee and eeeeeeeeeeee.

Comment: Please learn to use a debugger, for example `gdb`, to step through your program and watch values of variables. This way you can determine what your program is doing and what behavior is different from your expectation. This allows you to ask a specific question here. Also be aware that there is a maximum value `int` can hold. You do not verify that you do not exceed it, look at `std::numeric_limits` and use a larger type if necessary.

Comment: 1000000007 != 1000000009... is that important?